# Replace corrupt images with 404 image in react

Tags: reactjs, image

[image: Image not in correct format error]

Hi, on my webpage there are few images which are giving this response when going directly to the image link. I am using react in the frontend. Is it possible to check before loading these type of images that if there is no proper image at the location, load a not found image or 404 image. There are many ways which enable us to show 404 image if there is nothing at the link. But here I am getting something at the link but the webpage is not able to render this because its not in the correct format or whatever is the reason.  Is there any way to handle this in react?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could be helpfull, it has `onError` event - https://github.com/gokcan/react-shimmer  or look at the source code. I Imagine you would have to something similar as the `loadImage` method https://github.com/gokcan/react-shimmer/blob/master/src/web/index.js

Comment: Okay I am trying this

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onError` event handler on `<img>` tags like this :

```
import React from "react";

class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imageStatus: "loading", error: false };
  }

  handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "loaded", error: false });
  }

  handleImageError() {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "failed to load", error: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          src={this.state.error ? 'static/404.png' : this.props.imageUrl}
          onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}
          onError={this.handleImageError.bind(this)}
        />
        {this.state.imageStatus}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ImageComponent;
```